# Dataaccess help in three tier asp.net architecture

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have DAL function as

```
 public DataTable executeSelectQuery(String _query, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable = null;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            myCommand.Connection = openConnection();
            myCommand.CommandText = _query;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
            myAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error - Connection.executeSelectQuery - Query: 
        " + _query + " \nException: " + e.StackTrace.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

My button click

```
public void save_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string query = "Insert into customer_master(customer_title,customer_name)values(@parameter1,@parameter2)";
        SqlParameter[] sqlparam = new SqlParameter[2];
        sqlparam[0] = new SqlParameter("@parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        sqlparam[0].Value = ddl_title.SelectedValue;

        sqlparam[1] = new SqlParameter("@parameter2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        sqlparam[1].Value = txt_group_name.Text;

         string id = ms.insert(query, sqlparam);
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
          throw ex;
          }

         }
```

I want the button click function values to passed not as sqlparameter but as sql command object.How to do this with sqlcommand object instead of sqlparameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to pass around `SqlCommand` objects?? I wouldn't consider that an improvement of your current code - in the contrary!

Your UI code should really only pass **values** to the DAL function - just a `List<int>` or two strings or something. The DAL should do all the database-related stuff like creating `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameters`

So in your case here, I would have a method `InsertCustomer` on your DAL something like this:

```
public void InsertCustomer(string customerName, string customerTitle)
{
  .... // do all the DB stuff here - create SqlCommand, fill in SqlParameter,
       // execute the query
}
```

and your UI code should call this like this:

```
MyDAL dal = new MyDAL();
dal.InsertCustomer(txt_group_name.Text, ddl_title.SelectedValue);
```

There should be **no trace whatsoever** of ADO.NET classes or function in your UI code layer! So don't create `SqlCommand` or even `SqlParameter` in your UI layer - encapsulate this in the DAL layer! That what it's for!